# GridView SelectedIndexChange with Try Catch Block faulty in 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am using ASP.NET 2.0.

When i place a TRY CATCH block in my event it always go into the CATCH section, in my case it re-direct the page to Default.aspx. But if I remove the TRY CATCH block the code get's executed fine and it does what it suppose to.

```
Protected Sub gridResults1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles gridResults1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Try

        Dim selectedRowIndex As Integer
        selectedRowIndex = gridResults1.SelectedIndex

        Dim row As GridViewRow = gridResults1.Rows(selectedRowIndex)
        Dim theCompanyProfile As String = gridResults1.DataKeys(selectedRowIndex).Value

        Response.Redirect("Report.aspx?ID=" + theCompanyProfile)

    Catch ex As Exception

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")

    End Try

End Sub
```

- There is no error message when i place a break point by the "Catch ex As Exception"
- Am I reading the selectedRowIndex DataKey value incorrectly maybe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strange, can you try logging the exception message?

Comment: What do you mean by logging the message? When i go through all the properties of the message they are all saying "error: cannot obtain value"

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `Response.Redirect` method terminates the execution thread of the page and throws an `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException`.

You can catch the ThreadAbortException and ignore it (not a best practice, I guess), or pass `false` for the second parameter (`endResponse`) to the `Response.Redirect` method.

Check out this page for more info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, are you setting the DataKeyNames property on the GridView?